# While using the sticky table header plugin i am missing my last one data from the table?

Tags: jquery

I have number of data in a table. When I am freezing the headers of table, when i scroll down , i am unable to see the last one data from the table. Can anyone say why its happening .

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".fixHeader").stickyTableHeaders();
});
```

**HTML**

```
<table id="rcj" class="table grid xPagination fixHeader" cellpadding="8" cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%;height:100%">
        <thead>
        <tr style="color: #E4F2FC; background: #214F8F" align="center">
        <th style="padding-left:30px;border: none;text-align:center;">S.No </th>
        <th style="padding-left:30px;border: none;text-align:center;">Employee Name</th>
        <th style="padding-left:30px;border: none;text-align:center;">From</th>
        <th style="padding-left:30px;border: none;text-align:center;">Id</th>

        </tr>

        </thead>


                    <tbody><tr>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>works Home</td>
                        <td>Hyd</td>
                        <td>2342344</td>

                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>A240167ksn b 123469833</td>
                        <td>sec</td>
                        <td>8952646</td>

                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>3</td>
                        <td>Abhijna S</td>
                        <td>MP</td>
                        <td>988452</td>

                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>4</td>
                        <td>A240167ksn b 123469833</td>
                        <td>UP</td>
                        <td>875465</td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>5</td>
                        <td>Bhavani</td>
                        <td>2016-04-26 10:02:41 AM</td>
                        <td>2016-04-26 11:17:21 AM</td>
                        <td>1 hours   14 minutes </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>6</td>
                        <td>Lava Andriod</td>
                        <td>2016-04-26 02:27:24 PM</td>
                        <td>2016-04-26 02:37:17 PM</td>
                        <td>9 minutes </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>7</td>
                        <td>Lava Andriod</td>
                        <td>2016-04-26 03:38:06 PM</td>
                        <td>2016-04-26 04:05:02 PM</td>
                        <td>26 minutes </td>
                    </tr>
```

I have records of 7.but i am only visible to 6

Comment: got a fiddle/code example that reproduces the issue

Comment: Post your full code to check...

Comment: I have updated the question.Please check it once